# Stop spec after specific errors

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I use Protractor for e2e testing. And I try to stop tests execution after specific errors (not all and not only after first error (like fast-fail)).
I tried to use promises, process and so on.
If I write: process.exit(1) it works, but all specs after it in suite aren't started. 
Maybe somebody know how I can stop current spec (steps into describe after specific errors)?

My idea is use it into .waitReady() method:

```
waitReady = function(opt_optStr) {
  var self = this;
  var driverWaitIterations = 0;
  var lastWebdriverError;
  function throwError() {

   //STOP EXECUTING!!

    throw new Error("Expected '" + self.locator().toString() +
            "' to be present and visible. " +
            "After " + driverWaitIterations + " driverWaitIterations. " +
            "Last webdriver error: " + lastWebdriverError);
  }

  function isPresentError(err) {
    lastWebdriverError = (err != null) ? err.toString() : err;

    //STOP EXECUTING!!

    return false;
  }

  return browser.driver.wait(function() {
    driverWaitIterations++;
    if (opt_optStr === 'withRefresh' && driverWaitIterations > 7) {
      refreshPage();
    }
    return self.isPresent().then(function(present) {
      if (present) {
        return self.isDisplayed().then(function(visible) {
          lastWebdriverError = 'visible:' + visible;
          return visible;
        }, isPresentError);
      } else {
        lastWebdriverError = 'present:' + present;
        return false;
      }
    }, isPresentError);
  }, 10000).then(function(waitResult) {
    if (!waitResult) {
      throwError();
    }
    return waitResult;
  }, function(err) {
    isPresentError(err);
    throwError();
    return false;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Привет!

Seems like one of these libraries might help - 
https://github.com/Updater/jasmine-fail-fast
https://github.com/F1LT3R/protractor-jasmine2-fail-whale

They based on jasmine 2 reporters.